# How is DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER handled for anonymous users?

Tags: blocks

If a block is set to use `DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER` for caching, will the block be unique for each anonymous user, or the same for all anonymous users?

For reference from API docs:
[hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)
[DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/constant/DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER/7)

Looking at `includes/common.inc` source it appears to be based on `uid`, so I'd assume it would use the same block for all anonymous users (`uid = 0`), but wanted to double-check in case I could use this instead of `DRUPAL_NO_CACHE` (doing geolocation-driven results in the block).

```
elseif ($granularity & DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER) {
  $cid_parts[] = "u.$user->uid";
}
```

*(lines 6084-6086)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If a user is not logged in then uid is 0. So all anon users share the same user id.

I guess you will have to do your own caching, e.g. based on the IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  Yes, the IP address approach is what I'm pursuing now.  Only trouble with that is if someone is VPN'd into a network while traveling remotely, but fairly edge case I hope.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option to "Cache pages for anonymous users" in Drupal 7.

Admin->Configuration->Performance Look in the Caching Group just below the Clear Cache button.

Comment: The OP is aware of that. He is asking if blocks can be cached uniquely for *each* anonymous user.